# VBA Excel Sendkeys ARROW don't work in cmd.exe

Tags: vba, excel, cmd

i have some troubles when i will use another key than `"{ENTER}"`.

`"{UP}"`, `"{DOWN}"`, `"{LEFT}"` and `"{RIGHT}"` don't work in `cmd.exe`, why ?

```
Private Sub press_key(key As String)
    SendKeys key, True
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
End Sub

Sub Test()

Call Shell("C:\ ... \name.EXE", vbNormalFocus)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
press_key ("{ENTER}")
press_key ("{ENTER}")
press_key ("{DOWN}")
press_key ("{DOWN}")
press_key ("{DOWN}")
press_key ("{RIGHT}")
press_key ("{DOWN}")
press_key ("{DOWN}")
press_key ("{DOWN}")
press_key ("{ENTER}")

End Sub
```

[image: Excel launch the console]

Comment: Can you use any others (such as "a", or "b")? Or is it just the directional sendkeys that aren't working?

Comment: All keys work in anothers applications. Same for arrows. "a" "b", "c", ... do nothing but because the program don't use them. Here only arrows don't work.

Comment: Someone has a solution? There is an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to `Wait` one second between each SendKey.  Rather than `wait`ing, give focus to the app between SendKeys:

```
Private Sub press_key(key As String)
    SendKeys key, True
    DoEvents
End Sub
```

This will improve the interface between VBA and the app.

Comment: if i don't wait, the script send keys too quickly and the cmd.exe miss some keys. How i give the focus to my Shell call ?

Comment: @Rodrigue  Please try to include **both** the `Wait` and the `DoEvents` ...............is there any improvement ??

Comment: With `Wait`, and `DoEvents` ? No change. Like the program does not recognize the key.